# Why is this function Borel measurable?

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose that $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ is Borel measurable. Then $$h:\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$$ given by $$h(x,y)=f(x)+y$$ is Borel measurable. The only reason I was given was: $h$ is measurable since $f$ is, but I cannot seem to write down an explicit argument!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider $h$ as the composition:
$$\mathbf R\times\mathbf R\xrightarrow{(f,1_{\mathbf R})}\mathbf R\times\mathbf R\xrightarrow{\enspace s\enspace}\mathbf R,$$
where $s$ is addition.

The first map is the product (in the sense of set theory) of two measurable functions, hence it is measurable, $s$ is measurable, and the composition of measurable functions is measurable.

Answer (score 3):

The function $h$ is measurable if the set $h^{-1}\big((-\infty,r)\big)$ is measurable for every real number $r$. Now $h(x,y)<r$ if and only if there are rational numbers $q$ and $p$ such that $f(x)<q$, $y<p$, and $q+p<r$. Use this to write $h^{-1}\big((-\infty,r)\big)$ as the countable union of measurable sets.